# Can't find variable: FB?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to load a page with `jquery.load`, and after I have loaded it, I'm trying to run this code in that page:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

and then I get the error: `Can't find variable: FB`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the Facebook Javascript SDK first. See [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for multiple ways to do that.